# ¿Cómo se llama el tipo de notación todo en mayúsculas?

Tags: cobol

ya sé que es una pregunta un tanto absurda, quizás, pero me está comiendo el no encontrar el tipo de notación que tienen lenguajes como COBOL, por ejemplo, todo en mayúsculas. Por ejemplo:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION
```

Conozco el resto de notaciones típicas, pero no consigo encontrar esta.

Comment: Busca como se llama esa notación, como IdentificationDivision es "Pascal Case" o identificationDivision es "Camel Case"?

Comment: Ya, eso hice, pero no encuentro por ningún lado como se llama esa notación con todo en mayúsculas. Las típicas si, esta no. Por eso he preguntado aquí, por si alguien lo sabe.